# Setting variable in if statement turns into a loop, can this be solved with switch-case?

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

So basically I have this:

```
 if ($link == "badsimXX1.7.8.9&launchtype=medium") {
 $linky=("launchtype=medium");
 }

 if ($link == "badsimXX&1.8.5.2launchtype=large") {
 $linky=("launchtype=large");
 }

 if ($link == "badsimXX&1.9.2.4launchtype=small") {
 $linky=("launchtype=small");
 }

 if ($link == "badsimXX&1.2.5.2launchtype=tiny") {
 $linky=("launchtype=tiny");
 }

 if ($link == "badsimXX&1.6.4.5launchtype=itsy") {
 $linky=("launchtype=itsy");
 }
 ?>
```

And I later used this to redirect to a page, which resulted in a loop. So I tried to solve it with switch:

```
switch($linky){
case 1:
   $link='badsimXX1.7.8.9&launchtype=medium';
   break;
case 2:
   $link='badsimXX&1.8.5.2launchtype=large';
   break;
case 3:
   $link='badsimXX&1.9.2.4launchtype=small';
 }
```

But that didn't work. So either I can't solve it like that or there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: if $linky = ("launchtype=medium") how can it then be 1 or 2 or 3 as in the switch?

Answer (score 1):

Just put your strings into an associative array and check if the key exists and if yes assign the corresponding value to the variable or if not use a default value. Like this:

```
$check = ["badsimXX1.7.8.9&launchtype=medium" => "launchtype=medium", 
          "badsimXX&1.8.5.2launchtype=large" => "launchtype=large", 
          "badsimXX&1.9.2.4launchtype=small" => "launchtype=small", 
          "badsimXX&1.2.5.2launchtype=tiny" => "launchtype=tiny", 
          "badsimXX&1.6.4.5launchtype=itsy" => "launchtype=itsy"
         ];

if(isset($check[$link]))
    $linky = $check[$link];
else
    $linky = "default";
```

If you want to fix your switch statement:

1. You use the wrong variable for the switch statement

So change:

```
switch($linky) {
          //^ See here
```

to:

```
switch($link) {
         //^^ See here
```

2. You have to put your values into the case statement

Take the values from your if conditions and put it into the case statements, e.g.

```
case "badsimXX1.7.8.9&launchtype=medium":
```

3. Assign the corresponding value to the correct variable

Then assign as in your if statements the values to the correct variable:

```
$linky = "launchtype=medium";
   //^ See here
```

Comment: has to fix the switch to

Comment: @Dagon Also fixed the switch statement :)

Comment: great, now make me a sandwich

Comment: @Dagon I don't think that will be that delicious if I send it all the way down to new Zealand :D

Comment: but the  swiss cheeses will be authentic :-)

Comment: @Dagon huh, lol what happend with OP? (Also see his second revision: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30384248/2)

Comment: all that work you did for him - some people are so ungrateful